# CommandButon 's actionListener not working

Tags: java, jsf, converters, selectonemenu, commandbutton

Mi actionListener  in commandButton  is not called after i select an item in a h:selectOneMenu, only it works when i press button witout any selection in selectOneMenu
Below you can see my code:

```
<h:form id="formBtnBusquedaAnomalias">
                <table>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                                <h:outputLabel id="idEstatusAnomalias" value="Estatus anomalias." />                                     
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuEstatusAnomalias" 
                                    value = "#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.selectedEstatusAnomaliaVO}" >
                                    <f:converter converterId="estatusAnomaliaConverter"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.lstEstatusAnomaliaVOs}" var="estatusAnomalia"
                                        itemLabel="#{estatusAnomalia.descripcionEstatusAnomalia}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>                      
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>    
                            <p:commandButton value="Buscar anomalias."
                                    actionListener="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.buscarAnomalias()}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </h:form>
```

converter class:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "estatusAnomaliaConverter")
public class EstatusAnomaliaConverter implements Converter{

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {
    EstatusAnomaliaVO estatusAnomaliaVO = new EstatusAnomaliaVO();
    estatusAnomaliaVO.seDescripcionEstatusAnomalia(value);
    return estatusAnomaliaVO;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    String temp = "";
            if(!object == null)
            {
                 temp = object.toString();
            }
    return temp;
}
```

}

ManageBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name=ConstantesManageBeans.MANAGE_BEAN_BUSQUEDA_ANOMALIAS)
@RequestScoped
public class BusquedaAnomaliasManageBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1955257440354260445L;


public void buscarAnomalias(){
             //...some code here
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `buscarAnomalias` method doesn't follow the signature of an ActionListener method. This is the signature:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

In order to make it work, just add the `ActionEvent` parameter to your method:

```
public void buscarAnomalias(ActionEvent event) {
    //...some code here
}
```

If I were you, I would use `action` instead of `actionListener` to perform managed bean operations:

```
<p:commandButton value="Buscar anomalias."
   action="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.buscarAnomalias()}" />
```

Note that using this approach, you don't need to add the `ActionEvent event` parameter to your method.

More info:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267/1065197)

Another problem in your code is that your `FacesConverter` is failing when retrieving the value of the selected item. This is because you haven't set `itemValue` in your `<f:selectItems>`:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuEstatusAnomalias" 
    value="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.selectedEstatusAnomaliaVO}">
    <f:converter converterId="estatusAnomaliaConverter"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.lstEstatusAnomaliaVOs}"
         var="estatusAnomalia" itemValue="#{estatusAnomalia}"
         itemLabel="#{estatusAnomalia.descripcionEstatusAnomalia}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: This restriction no longer persists : https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html. Might also depend on OP's version of JSF though

Comment: @kolossus is your link broken? I try to access but it only shows a blank page and keeps loading.

Comment: Can't believe it myself but it seems that link died overnight. Try this https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza i made changes as your answer and the same error continue. let me explain better: when i press the button the action method buscarAnomalias() works fine then when y select an item in the selectOneMenu and press again button the action method dosen´t no anything

Comment: @Aredalo I have also added a section about the `<h:selectOneMenu>`, have you tried it?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza yes, i changed the attribute actionListener to action="#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.buscarAnomalias()}" and also i added itemValue="#{estatusAnomalia}" attribute in <f:selectItems> tag and tried again

Comment: @Aredalo looks like a problem in your `FacesConverter`. Something is failing when converting the selected object into an instance of `estatusAnomalia`. Also, make sure that `value=#{busquedaAnomaliasManageBean.selectedEstatusAnomaliaVO}` is from the same type of `#{estatusAnomalia}`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what does itemValue = "#{estatusAnomalia}" mean? because i just added because of your answer but i dont really understand it. Converter looks ok because i put some system.out inside and this method is working but this method is called when i press the commandButton, this converter is not called whean i change selection in selectOneMenu

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is it necesary also to implement hashcode and equals method in EstatusAnomaliaVO?